# How to copy type annotations from parent method that is overriden in the child class

Tags: python, python-typing

Given a child class that inherits from a parent class, the child class overrides some method, and the method signature is the same as the parents (including type annotations), how do I not repeat the same type annotations in the overriden method?

The example below seems to work well for Pydantic. I am not sure if this is the intention of type annotations or specific to the type checker implementation.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    ...

  def method(self, a: int, b: int) -> bool:
    return a > b

class B(A):

  def method(self, a, b):
    return a <= b
```

[image]

Comment: No, type hints are never inherited. It might be `Pydantic` implementation detail (traversing MRO while signature doesn't change until type hints are found), but `mypy` and (AFAIC) `pyright` won't do this, considering your `method` unannotated.

Comment: I assume you want `def method(self, a: int, b: str)` -> `def method(self, a: int, b: int)` so you avoid `Operator "<=" not supported for types "int" and "str"`?

Comment: @TonyN Yes, that's a typo. Please feel free to suggest an edit next time.

Comment: @Keto Sorry about that. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Anyone would like to implement a "copy type hints" decorator?